# GameKit Device Identification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit

In ios gamekit framework, what is the code to identify the names of the devices that are connected together?

Answer (score 2):

With your [GKSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKSession) you can get all peers with a specified state then get their name.

```
//Get all connected peers
NSArray *peerIds = [gksession peersWithConnectionState: GKPeerStateConnected];
for(NSString *peerId in peerIds)
{
    //Log the peer name
    NSLog(@"%@", [gksession displayNameForPeer:peerID]);
}
```